# What is the meaning of $\sin(0.876726)$ here?

Tags: trigonometry

one of the solution of $x^2-\sin(x)=0$ is $x\approx 0.876726$  according to [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2-sin%28x%29%3D0)

Therefor $0.876726^2-\sin(0.876726)\approx0$

But my question is what is the meaning of $\sin(0.876726)$ and how to calculate its value?

I guess it means $0.876726$ radian. If it is true I don't understand why root of $f(x)=x^2-\sin(x)$ should be presented as radian.

Comment: Surely you don't suggest using (gasp) *degrees*, do you?

Comment: It is indeed radians. Remember that radian is a unitless quantity. It is defined as the length of an arc divided by radius (meters divided by meters)

Comment: @Andrei ok. but I don't completely understand why the root is automatically expressed as radian

Comment: Because that's how $\sin$ function is defined. See the answer below. If you want to define it in degrees, you would write your problem as $x^2-\sin(x^\circ)=0$

Comment: I got it. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When talking about the $\sin(x)$, $x$ is always in radians.

Whenever you have something like $\sin(30^\circ)$ it actually means $\sin(\frac{30^\circ\pi}{180^\circ})$.

To calculate the value of $x$ in the equation:

$$x^2 - \sin(x) = 0$$ you would have to use a numerical method, such as Newton-Raphson.

In this case, you would consider an initial guess $x_0$ such as $x_0 =1$ and then apply the following iteration function.

$$x_{i+1}=x_i - \frac{f(x_i)}{f'(x_i)}$$

Where $f(x)=x^2-\sin(x)$ and $f'(x)=2x-\cos(x)$

For our choice of $x_0$ we get:
$$x_0=1$$
$$x_1=0.891395$$
$$x_2=0.876984$$
$$x_3=0.876726$$
$$x_4=0.876726$$